# How to send google pay "Request" via android java like amazon bhim pay online payment

Tags: java, android, payment, google-pay, upi

How to send Google Pay or Bhim UPI request via app. I know about this but I want to send payment request:

```
try {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay?pa="+payeeAddress+"&pn="+payeeName+"&tn="+transactionNote+
    "&am="+amount+"&cu="+currencyUnit);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);}

catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry! Please Install GPAY or BHIM", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("upi://pay? 
pa=payee_address&pn=payee_name&tn=transaction_name&am=1&cu=INR&url=url");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setClassName("in.org.npci.upiapp","in.org.npci.upiapp.HomeActivity");
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```